# Add Rules to Stylesheets with JavaScript - insertRule not working

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm learning about using **JavaScript** to make the **CSS** more dynamic but for some reason, this code here won't work. I'm developing inside **Visual Studio**, the IntelliSense does not even show me the method insertRule. As a basis I use this documentation for learning:

https://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript

I do the same as written there but somehow I can't use the function on the object.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var bar = newSheet();
    bar.insertRule("header { float: left; opacity: 0.8; }", 1);  
};

function newSheet() {
    // Create the <style> tag
    var style = document.createElement("style");
    //WebKit Hack
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
    // Add the <style> element to the page
    document.head.appendChild(style);

    return style.sheet;
};
```

Comment: There's no need for `insertRule` or anything to do with stylesheets, when you've just created the style tag yourself. Just do `style.innerHTML = 'css...'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Element `style` works just like any other DOM tag, and as such, you can use innerHTML to append styles to it, since you already created the element from javascript, you just need to modify its value:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var bar = newSheet();
  bar.insertRule("header { float: left; opacity: 0.8; }", 1);  
};

function newSheet() {
 // Create the <style> tag
 var style = document.createElement("style");

 style.innerHTML="p{color:red;}";
 style.innerHTML+="h1{color:green;}";

 //WebKit Hack
 style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(""));
 // Add the <style> element to the page
 document.head.appendChild(style);

 return style.sheet;
};
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what appending the textNode helps with?